# How can I inject a singleton bean from one blueprint.xml into a separate blueprint.xml?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, blueprint-osgi

I have a Java class that serves as a registry of multiple other classes that represent entities (in my example, varieties of apples). There are two major steps to this:

1. The **entities** get defined in blueprintA. The **registry** also gets populated in blueprintA. My understanding is that blueprint automatically handles the right order as part its dependency injection process (and across blueprint.xml files).
2. A **resource** class gets created and has the registry injected either as an argument of the constructor or as an argument to a property setter. In my case, I used a bean setter.

## blueprintA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="AppleRegistry" class="com.domain.AppleRegistry" activation="lazy" scope="singleton">
        <property name="apples">
            <set value-type="com.domain.apple.IApple">
                <ref component-id="macintosh" />
                <ref component-id="baldwin" />
                <ref component-id="stayman" />
                <ref component-id="crispin" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="macintosh" class="com.domain.apple.IApple"/>
    <bean id="baldwin" class="com.domain.apple.IApple"/>
    <bean id="stayman" class="com.domain.apple.IApple"/>
    <bean id="crispin" class="com.domain.apple.IApple"/>

</blueprint>
```

## blueprintB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="AppleResource" class="com.domain.api.AppleResource" scope="singleton">
        <property name="appleRegistry">
            <ref component-id="AppleRegistry" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</blueprint>
```

I would expect my code to work, but I am getting errors in the log, including:

> `Unable to load com.domain.api.AppleResource from recipe BeanRecipe[name='AppleResource'], trying to load a nested class com.domain.api$AppleResource`

I am aware that I left out the bean implementations, but this question is not about them. I could type up some code upon request, should those be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both AppleRegistry and AppleResource are top-level managers, Blueprint cannot automatically determine the dependency between them (like implicit dependencies of submanagers). It must be explicitly declared:

- `depends-on="com.domain.OtherTopLevelManager"`

Example

```
<bean id="AppleResource" class="com.domain.api.AppleResource" scope="singleton" depends-on="AppleRegistry">
        <property name="appleRegistry">
            <ref component-id="AppleRegistry" />
        </property>
</bean>
```